# What is x+y and xy given x=1000 bits and y=500 bits?

Tags: algorithm

Given x=1000 bits and y=500 bits, what is the longest length x+y and xy?

FYI: The answer should not be 1500 for x+y and 750k, which is why I'm confused :(

Comment: Define “longest length”. And what makes you think “1500 for x+y” is not the answer?

Comment: This was on a quiz I just had but I'm not sure it's correct because it says the answer must be accurate within +10 and -10

Comment: Do you mean you're adding a 1,000 bit number to a 500 bit number?

Comment: Use logs. - xy is going to be the largest

Comment: The downvotes are probably because the question needs more clarity for what you are asking.  You probably need to clarify whether you mean x+y as addtion and xy as multiplication.

Answer (score 3):

If the length of *x* is between 0 and 1000 bits, then the value of *x* is between 0 and 2<sup>1000</sup>−1. Similarly, 0 ≤ *y* < 2<sup>500</sup>.

So, 0 ≤ *x* + *y* ≤ 2<sup>1000</sup> + 2<sup>500</sup> − 2 < 2<sup>1001</sup>, so *x* + *y* has length at most 1001.

Similarly, 0 ≤ *xy* < 2<sup>1500</sup>, *xy* has length at most 1500.

Comment: I think that's right...

Comment: @ChuckCottrill: Arbitrary-precision values do not have a concept of "overflow", only a concept of "out of memory". If you run out of memory after less than 1500 bits, then you can't be using Stack Overflow anyway, so my answer doesn't need to help you. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Think of it as given a number from 0-99, and you add a number 0-9, how many digits are you going to need at most? 3 (2+1). And if you have an number 0-9999 and you add a number 0-99, you are going to need at most 5 digits (4+1). Notice how it is the number of digits of the largest number plus one. So the answer is 1001.

Answer (score 0):

Consider 2 bit numbers. In the worst case you can get:

```
11b + 11b = 110b
```

So 3 bits is enough, not 2 + 2. For the number at most `N` you need `ceil(log(N))` bits (where `log` means logarithm with base `2`). So if you have two numbers at most `N` and at most `M` you'll need `ceil(log(N+M))` bits.

For multiplication, consider 3 bit numbers:

```
111b * 111b = 110001b
```

That's why it's also not a simple multiplication of the number of bits of the arguments. Similarly to the above for multiplication you need `ceil(log(N*M))` bits.

Comment: 11b * 11b = 1001b (3*3 = 9)

Answer (score 0):

Answer depends upon how you want to handle overflow (and how you define the functions `+` and `*`).

lets adopt the notation `var:bitwidth` to mean variable has bitwidth bits.  That would mean you have the following declarations,

```
x:1000
y:500
```

Furthermore, we adopt the convention that these are stored in bigendian order (rightmost bit is smallest bit, leftmost is largest bit).  We quickly conclude that `x+y` needs 1001 to handle overflow bit, that is,

```
z0:1000, z1:1001
z0 = x + y //overflow possible, ex: x=2^1000-1, y=1
z1 = x + y //overflow not possible
```

Multiplication is harder,  consider `a:8`, `b:8`, what is the widest result?

```
a:8, b:8
a = 11111111b //= 255
b = 11111111b //= 255
a * b == 1111111000000001 //=65025
//16 bits
```

Seems reasonable to expect that the number of bits needed for multiplication is the sum of the bits, unless you want to just have an overflow bit for multiplication overflow.

```
x:1000, y:5000
z:1500
z2:1499
z = x * y //would not have overflow
z2 = x * y //could have overflow
```

All this said, normal microprocessors just use the width of the larger (`:1000`), and either drop overflow or set an overflow bit.  So the answer is `:1000` or `:1000` plus `:1`